# Remove focus and active effects from Bottom Sheet

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to remove the effects that occurs when you click on the button and after clicking by default. In other words, when its :focus and :active.

```
<button mat-raised-button click="openBottomSheet()" class="options-menu">
 <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
```

I have removed the default styles with the `box-shadow` but I can't remove in these two actions.

```
.options-menu {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

I remove the `box-shadow` also in this two actions, but the background still being grey.

```
.options-menu:focus:active {
    background-color: transparent!important;
    box-shadow: none!important;
}
```

I also try this why, but the grey background continous:

```
.options-menu .mat-mdc-button-persistent-ripple::before {
  box-shadow: none!important;
  background-color: transparent!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `[disableRipple]="true"` on the button to remove the click effect

```
<button mat-raised-button click="openBottomSheet()" class="options-menu" [disableRipple]="true">
  <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
</button>
```

and add the below style to remove the click shadow effect:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-raised-button:not(.mat-button-disabled):active:not([class*=mat-elevation-z]) {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);

    // box-shadow: none; to remove the shadow
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It removes de click effect, but still appear the :active one

Comment: Try to uncomment the second line (// box-shadow: none; to remove the shadow), and comment the first one